# Change State on Press

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to change the string inside my Text element when I tap the TouchableOpacity. But whenever I tap it gives me an error of this.setState is not a function.

Here's my code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        sampleText: "Click Here"
    };
}

clickText() {
    this.setState({
        sampleText: 'Hello World'
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.clickText}>
                <View style={[styles.avatar, styles.avatarContainer]}>
               <Text>{this.state.sampleText}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For `React.Component` es6 classes you need to bind the callback's context to `this` (your class instance). You may be used to `React.createClass` which does some binding for you behind the scenes:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.clickText.bind(this)}>
```

You could also bind with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={e => this.clickText(e)}>
```